# django-piston method is not allowed

Tags: django, jquery, django-piston

I have this:

*handlers.py*

```
class ChatHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = ChatMsg
    allowed_methods = ('POST','GET')

    def create(self, request, text):
        message = ChatMsg(user = request.user, text = request.POST['text'])
        message.save()
        return message
```

*template.html*

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.chat-btn').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/post/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: {text: $('.chat').val()}
            })
        })
    })
    </script>
    ...
```

*api/urls.py*

```
chat_handler = Resource(ChatHandler, authentication=HttpBasicAuthentication)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^chat/$', chat_handler, {'emitter_format': 'json'}),
)
```

Why, but POST method is allowed in ChatHandler? GET method is working. Is it bug, or my code is wrong?

Comment: Your url pattern doesnt capture a param to pass to the create methods text parameter. Isnt it crashing on that or is this not an accurate example?

Comment: it is not crashing, i have error 405 method is not allowed in firebug's console

Comment: Why is your `ChatHandler` routed to url `api/chat` but your javascript is POSTing to `/api/post/`? What is routed at that url endpoint?

Comment: this code is a short version, api/urls.py included in general urls.py    url(r'api/', include('api.urls')),

Comment: I understand. But your examples here dont match. What is on the other end of api/post ? What handler?

Comment: you can see my full example in [GITHUB](https://github.com/lightwolf03/prog) in api/* and in templates

Comment: It was exactly as I expected, now that you showed your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you didn't include this code in your question, I found it in your github you gave in comments...

You are mapping to a handler that does not allow POST requests

**urls.py** ::snip::

```
post_handler = Resource(PostHandler, authentication=auth)
chat_handler = Resource(ChatHandler, authentication=auth)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/$', post_handler , { 'emitter_format': 'json' }),
    url(r'^chat/$', chat_handler, {'emitter_format': 'json'}),
)
```

**handlers.py**

```
# url: '/api/post'
# This has no `create` method and you are not 
# allowing POST methods, so it will fail if you make a POST
# request to this url
class PostHandler(BaseHandler):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    # refuses POST requests to '/api/post'
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)


    def read(self, request):
        ...

# ur;: '/api/chat'
# This handler does have both a POST and GET method allowed.
# But your javascript is not sending a request here at all.
class ChatHandler(BaseHandler):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatMsg
    allowed_methods = ('POST', 'GET')

    def create(self, request, text):
        ...

    def read(self, request):
        ...
```

Your javascript requests is being sent to `'/api/post/'`, which is being routed to the `PostHandler`. I get the sense that you expected it to go to the chat handler. That means you need to change the javascript request url to `'/api/chat/'`, or move the code to the handler you expected.

Also, you are setting the model wrong in the handlers. It does not need a `Meta` nested class. It should be:

```
class PostHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = Post

class ChatHandler(BaseHandler):
    model = ChatMsg
```

Comment: but GET method is working in this handler. url in js is true, because it included in main urls.py.  `url(r'api/', include('api.urls'))` and `urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/$', post_handler , { 'emitter_format': 'json' }),
    url(r'^chat/$', chat_handler, {'emitter_format': 'json'}),
)`
after this i have working Get on '/api/chat', but Post method not working

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I am saying. You have **NO** POST method defined or allowed on the `PostHandler`. And you are trying to make a POST request to the url `/api/post/`. It is very clear  here what is wrong.

Comment: there can be I am mistaken, but post request is passed, i have `AttributeError at /api/chat/

'HttpResponseServerError' object has no attribute '_is_string'`

Comment: Are you saying that you changed your javascript url to `/api/chat` and it is now making the request but getting an error?

Comment: sorry for my english, you can misunderstand me. browser send POST request to handler, process enter in handler but on the creating object "message" i have error `AttributeError at /api/chat/ 'HttpResponseServerError' object has no attribute '_is_string'`

Comment: Well this problem seems unrelated to your original question. It is probably [this logged Issue #221](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/issue/221/attributeerror-httpresponseservererror) which would occur if you are using django 1.4 in combination with unicode content instead of string content

Comment: well, am i need to patch piston?

Comment: If you are indeed using the same setup as listed in that issue...then I would assume so.